# Django. Use url tags inside quotes, inside quotes

Tags: django, url, tags, escaping, quotes

I want to pass this variable to the context and render it, it includes html tags.

```
notificacion_string = "<a href = \"{% url \'perfiles:perfil\' actor.usuario.username  \'recientes\' %}\" > %s </a> voted on your post" % (notificacion.actor.usuario.username)
```

As you can see, I have tried escaping the quotes inside the href=" ". But I get this error:

```
%u format: a number is required, not unicode
```

So, I guess the error happens when **"% url .." %()** is evaluated. I have tried many things without success.

Extra information:

The url "pefiles:perfil" recieves two arguments:

```
 url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<queryset>\w+)/$',views.perfil, name='perfil'),
```

the arguments are a username and a queryset, the first one comes from notificacion.actor.usuario.username and the second one is a string, 'recientes'.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{% url ... %}` is a template mechanism. Do not try to use it from outside a template. Rather, do yourself in the view what it would do:

### Generate URL in view

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Generate the URL using the Django urlresolver reverse
url = reverse('perfiles:perfil', kwargs={'username': actor.usuario.username, 'queryset': 'recientes' })

# Then concatenate the URL as other string argument
notificacion_string = "<a href ='%s'> %s </a> voted on your post" % (url, notificacion.actor.usuario.username)
```

The official Django documentation is quite well-explained so I recommend you check  [Django URLresolvers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urlresolvers/)

For comparison, here are two other ways how links can be generated (unrelated to your question):

### Generate URL in template (HTML)

```
<a href = "{% url 'perfiles:perfil' actor.usuario.username  'recientes' %}" >{{notificacion.actor.usuario.username}}</a> voted on your post"
```

### Generate URL in jQuery in template

```
<script>
    // Generate an URL with a fake username
    var url = "{% url 'perfiles:perfil' 'FakeUsername'  'recientes' %}"

    // Let's supose we received an AJAX response with a variable username
    username = response['username']

    // Replace the string 'FakeUsername' for the real one
    url = url.replace('FakeUsername', username)
</script>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to escape any of those quotes. The context for evaluating the code inside the template tag is completely separate from the surrounding HTML, so they do not interfere.

Comment: I still get the error "%u format: a number is required, not unicode". I guess the problem is "<a href = '{% url '...' %s ..%}'>%s</a>"%(...): the "% url" is read as a string with a unsigned decimal replacement. I don't know how to solve it. Thanks for the tip on quotes btw.